# Python: EOF error in pickle.load

Tags: python, pickle

I am following a tutorial and writing a code to store and retrieve cookies using pickle

```
import requests
import pickle
def save_cookies(cookies, filename):
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(cookies, f)

def load_cookies(filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                return pickle.load(f)


url = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/here'
data = {'value': 50, 'username': 'shreyUsr', 'password': 'pass'}
r = requests.post(url, data, cookies=load_cookies('cookie_store.dat'))
save_cookies(r.cookies, 'cookie_store.dat')

print("CLIENT SIDE: Status Code is " + str(r.status_code) + "Reason is " + str(r.reason) )
print("SERVER SIDE: Response is " + str(r.text))
```

Running the code gives the following error:

```
File "./cookieComm.py", line 15, in <module>
    r = requests.post(url, data, cookies=load_cookies('cookie_store.dat'))
  File "./cookieComm.py", line 10, in load_cookies
    return pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Please advice whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it your `cookie_store.dat` file is currently empty, because you are trying to load prior to saving the cookies on the following lines:

```
r = requests.post(url, data, cookies=load_cookies('cookie_store.dat'))
save_cookies(r.cookies, 'cookie_store.dat')
```